# Can libvlc encode the raw YUV or RGBA frames into a video file, like a mp4 file?

Tags: encode, libvlc, yuv

I know that libvlc can transcode many video formats. But how to use it to encode raw video frames? I just can't find related APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the memory access modules, which were introduced specifically for this use-case in the forthcoming v3.0 of libvlc. There is no public documentation for those as of yet.

Comment: It's such a good news, although I have solved my problem via another approach. And thanks for your answer.